# Implement link to new page using button and click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

Here is the server-side code snipped that handles GET request:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/html/index.html");
});

app.get("/new-html", function(req, res){
    console.log("Request /new-html");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/html/new.html");
})
```

And this is the code in the client-side that triggers the request:

```
    $("#load-html").click(function() {
        $.get("/new-html")
    })
```

The **index.hml** itself is rendered when the page is loaded and request with root url is made.

What I want is when I hit button with `id=load-html` to receive and render completely new html file returned by the server.

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ You are requesting the file, but discarding it.

Comment: I have read thi. It doesn't tell me how to render a valid html file. I dont want to nest html elements. Instead I want to load a complete html with the DOCTYPE body head and all that sh*t

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Put the received document inside an `<iframe>`? Navigate to it?

Comment: I am afraid you dont understand my questiion

Comment: I'm trying my best, and I'm not slow or anything. You are explaining it badly. WHERE do you want the browser to render the file...?

Comment: @Chris G
 Never mind Radar155 got the idea.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a link tag in your index.html page

```
<a href="/new-html">some text</a>
```

If you want to use javascript:

```
$("#load-html").click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/new-html'
})
```

Comment: `window.location.href` was exactly what I was looking for :)